# Composed messages using JSP and XML

Tags: java, xml, jsp, localization

I have a XML with messages, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<messages>
    <hello>Hi {1} welcome to {2}</hello>
</messages>
```

So I want to replace the {1} and {2} with some JSP variables and print the result:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>

/* set vars */
<c:set var="name" value="John Doe" />
<c:set var="location" value="Internet" />

/* import and parse xml */
<c:import url="messages.xml" var="messages" />
<x:parse xml="${messages}" var="xml" />

/* print message */
<x:out select="$xml/messages/hello" var="name" var="location"  />
```

The result of the last line should be:

```
Hi John Doe welcome to Internet
```

I'm trying to get this working but I'm completely lost. Can you help me to solve this or give me the name of this "technique" to keep looking for information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of tasks are generally referred as "*Internationalization*" or "*Templating*".

This is a simple approach of how you can do this with your existing code:

```
<c:set var="helloTemplate">
    <x:out select="$xml/messages/hello" />
</c:set>

<c:out value="<%= java.text.MessageFormat.format(helloTemplate, 
                                pageContext.getAttribute("name"), 
                                pageContext.getAttribute("location")) %>" />
```

Using scriptlets `(<%= .. %>)` in JSP is not the best way of doing things, instead you can create a function/tag that uses the MessageFormat internally. Example of creating custom tag: https://sites.google.com/a/pintailconsultingllc.com/java/custom-jsp-tag-libraries

Alternatively, If you have control over the message file, you can use properties file instead of the xml format (e.g. `messages.properties`) which will contain:

```
hello=Hi {1} welcome to {2}
```

This can then be used as follows:

```
<fmt:message key="hello">
    <fmt:param value="${name}" />
    <fmt:param value="${location}" />
</fmt:message>
```

This is generally referred to as "*Internationalization*" - more info: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnaxu/index.html

Comment: I don't have control over the properties file and I was trying to avoid the Java code in the view but this solution works and is better than nothing, thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

This is called (Message) Formatting and the `MessageFormat` class is exactly what you're looking for. Take a look at the JavaDoc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html